# Database Design Issue due to Volume

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a really generic database question.  I have created a table in my database that tracks clicks throughout my website. My table structure is as follows:

- (PK) - ID,
- (FK) - PageID,
- (FK) - ContactID,
- Date

The problem I am having is that with a large user set, and large volumes of click through data the number of rows in this table are in the 20-30 million range.  Is there a different way I could organize this data to make reporting by date easier?

```
SELECT P.TITLE, COUNT(DISTINCT(C.ID)) 
FROM PAGES P 
INNER JOIN CLICKS C ON C.PAGEID = P.PAGEID 
WHERE C.DATE >= 5/1/2013 AND C.DATE < 6/1/2013 AND C.PAGEID = XYZ
```

Comment: Why don't you keep this schema, and run a aggregate query once a day that puts the aggregate results into a separate table? The smaller aggregate table should be faster to query.

Comment: Do you have an index on Date?

Comment: Have a cron job periodically archive (and maybe aggregate?) data.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: Yes, the date column is indexed.

Comment: @Suman & Kevin: As for aggregating via a cron job, this isn't as straightforward in the environment I am running in.  I was hoping there was a way to split up this data to reduce the table size and attack it from that approach instead.  If that isn't possible then I will be forced to go that route.

Comment: Could you post some of the queries that are running slow? If you're looking for user data in a specific time frame you would want a user,date index.

Comment: 30 million rows isn't very much for any modern DBMS. Based on your table structure I'd estimate that's about 1-2GB, which is a small database by anyone's standards. If you are seriously having problems then either your software, the techniques you are using or your indexing is letting you down. It might help if you told us what DBMS and/or reporting software you are using.

Comment: do you care what a given contact's click distribution is throughout a given day, or that they just had say 50 clicks that day?

Comment: I need to be able to drill down into each contact's clicks, so it is important to maintain the datapoint.

I need to be able to:
View Pages Clicked and the # of times clicked, then Drill Down on the Page and see the Contacts that clicked the page and the number of times they clicked it, then drill down on the contact and see the times they clicked it.

Comment: All you have to do is add an index on `(DATE, PageID, ID)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oracle Partitions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/schemaob.htm#CNCPT112) handle this requirement beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

It's called dimensional design.

You can use a tool like Pentaho Aggregation Designer to find appropriate aggregations (such as clicks by customer by month).

Then use an OLAP tool like Mondrian + Saiku, that can dynamically rewrite your queries to use the aggregates when it is advantageous.

You should use a date dimension table with an integer smart-key† (like 20130621). This makes it easy to partition your visit facts by date.

Pentaho Data Integration can make it easy to partition your tables.

† this is the only time you should use a smart key in dimensional design.